# How to use WPF Bindings up to several levels

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, relativesource

Here's the problem I often encounter when I develop complex controls in WPF.

I want to bind some properties up to multiple levels of parent.

I'm currently using this with RelativeSource and TemplatedParent :

```
Value="{Binding PropertyToBind, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

But with this, you can just bind to the direct parent, and I have 4 levels... So I made 4 binding to finally bind to the good value.

I cannot remove my 4 levels of object, they are complex controls...

For example, my **first level** is my Joystick control. In my joystick, I have a Slider control (**2nd level**) to move up and down. In my Slider, I have a Button (**3rd level**). In my button, I have a Text (**4th level**) that I want to bind to a propety in my level 1 (Joystick).

What I do is I bind my text to a property in the button, then I bind the property of the button to the one in the Slider, etc.. to the Joystick. Sometimes, I need to create custom controls (with added properties where I can bind).

This is not my scenario, it's just an example (yes in this we can probably remove some levels but not in mine) I don't want an answer with: remove this or this object...

Is there a way to bind directly to multiple levels? Each level is a ControlTemplate in a Style.

I'm using WPF 4, .NET 4.0, Blend 4, Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the other permutations of `RelativeSource` in your binding?  Specifically, you can use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type SomeType}}` to find a specific control above you, which looks like it might work well for your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You should not do this, it breaks the encapsulation and intrOduces unnecessary dependencies. What you describes is the way to go:

> What I do is I bind my text to a property in the button, then I bind the property of the button to the one in the Slider, etc..

Comment: But when I have 10 properties to bind, I need to create everytime a custom control with 10 dependency property. (Custom control for Button, for Slider, etc etc.)

Comment: @mlemay: You are doing weird things if you need custom properties for everything. Also the DataContext is inherited all the way to your inner controls, why not use that? Or are you changing the DataContext all the time?

Comment: It's our graphic designer that create the hierarchy, and everything, he don't know more then how Bind to a property... he's not a programmer, we need to have a simple solution. I'll try to find something with DataContext thx

Comment: A note on the DataContext: You also should not use that inside control templates, it also breaks encapsulation. A control template should be completely stand-alone without any knowledge of data or other controls outside the templated control.